# Knockpy not detecting dnspython

Tags: python

I installed knockpy from github and tried running it but gave this error

> ImportError: No module named python-dnspython

I tried

```
pip install dnspython
```

and the output was

> Requirement already satisfied: dnspython in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (2.1.0.dev1)
> I am not being able to find the solution. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

You are importing it incorrectly, correct import:

```
import dns
```